# What does averaging over time means in literature?

Tags: kinetic-theory, statistics

**Disclaimer:** This question is cross posted in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269488/what-does-averaging-over-time-means-in-literature) because the answer might be field dependent.

Let $h: [0, L]\times \mathbb{Z}^1 \to \mathbb{Z}^1$ be a function, called the height function, and lets denote the mean value of $h$ at time $t$ be $\bar h(t)$.

In the paper *Anomaly in numerical integrations of the Kardar-Parisi-Zhang equation* by Chi-Hang Lam and F. G. Shin, Physical Review E, VOLUME 57, NUMBER 6, June 1998, at page 56, it is given that

> $$w := \left < \frac{ 1 \sum_{x=1}^L (h(x,t) - \bar h(t))}{ L}  \right
>  >^{1/2},$$
>
> where $L$ is the lattice size used in the numerical integration [...],
>   The brackets   denote ensemble averaging, which is equivalent to
>   averaging over time when steady state is being considered.

However, what do they mean by "ensemble average" and "averaging over time" ?

Comment: what can it possibly mean other than taking the integral of the function between $[0,T]$? :p

Comment: @gented Yes, but as a function of $T$ ? i.e for every T, we need to take the "ensemble average over time" between [0,T] ?

Comment: Well, all integrals are a function of the domain, after all. $\int_0^x dt f(t)$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the [ergodic hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis) in statistical mechanics. It is the hypothesis that in a system in equilibrium (steady state), averages of a given observable over many-system at one fixed time would be equal to the average of the same quantity on one system but over a long period of time.